# Create Postgres JSONB Index on Array Sub-Object for ILIKE operator

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing, sql-like, jsonb

I have a table that has cast as jsonb column, which looks like this:

```
cast: [
  { name: 'Clark Gable', role: 'Rhett Butler' },
  { name: 'Vivien Leigh', role: 'Scarlett' },
]
```

I'm trying to query name in the jsonb array of objects. This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor as name
FROM "Title", 
jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_path_query_array("Title".cast,'$[*].name')) actor
WHERE actor ILIKE 'cla%';
```

Is there a way to index a query like this? I've tried using BTREE, GIN, GIN with gin_trgm_ops with no success.
My attempts:

```
CREATE INDEX "Title_cast_idx_jsonb_path" ON "Title" USING GIN ("cast" jsonb_path_ops);
CREATE INDEX "Title_cast_idx_on_expression" ON "Title" USING GIN(jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_path_query_array("Title".cast, '$[*].name')) gin_trgm_ops);
```

One of the issues is that `jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_path_query_array())`returns a set which can't be indexed. Using array_agg doesn't seem useful, since I need to extract name value, and not just check for existence.

Comment: This would be a lot easier with a properly normalized data model

Comment: Or maybe at least if the JSON were valid JSON.